# Give a margin bottom to a div positioned absolutely and height: 100vh

Tags: css

I have a div positioned absolutely with a `height: 100vh`. It has also a shadow. No I would like to give it a 20px margin bottom in order to see the bottom shadow. Is that possible? any trick?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKpEt/3/)

```
<div class="container"><div class="aux"></div></div>

body {

    margin: 0;
}
.container {

    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    box-shadow: red 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `calc()` and subtract `20px` from height

```
height: calc(100vh - 20px);
```

---

Another approach, without using `calc()` but changing the markup, is to introduce an inner container, like so

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and this css

```
.container {
    -webkit-box-sizing: padding-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: padding-box;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;
    padding : 0 20px 20px 0; /* we create room for the box shadow inside the
                                container. Padding is included in the height 
                                due to the box-sizing property
                              */
}

.inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
    box-shadow: red 10px 10px 10px;  
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sp9bh/2/
[1]: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: Please note that `calc()` [is not working](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94158) with viewport units on Webkit browsers. Alternatively you could use `%` values for the absolutely positioned element as: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/XKpEt/5/ No need to alter the markup.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just add 20px to the bottom margin?

```
margin-bottom: 120px;
```

Comment: OK, a working approach has already been posted in another answer anyway